# CMAKE Make program не устанавливается

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, кросс-компиляция

Имеется cross компилятор для сборки на виндовс под линукс.
Пытаюсь написать Cmake скрипт сборки, а так-же toolchain файл.
При запуске первичная инициализация проходит, но при попытке запустить сборку командой `cmake --build .`  вылезает ошибка: `Cmake generator error: -f Makefile`
Тулчейн обычный, там прописаны пути до компилятора, линковщики и прочие.
Судя по всему проблема в make, который поставляется вместе с тулчейном. Если после инициализации вручную вызвать его, то проект собирается, но через cmake не выходит сбилдить. Путем проб и ошибок заметил, что в CmakeCache не устанавливатся переменная CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM. Если её выставить, то через cmake --build все работает.
Помогите пожалуйста, как заставить cmake в кеше выставлять эту переменную? В тулчейне я ее естественно выставляю
Использую опции генератора "Unix makefiles"

Тулчейн

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(SDK_PATH "c:/b70_sdk/B70_Application_Development_Environment/b70_sdk/b70_sdk")
set(toolchain_dir "c:/b70_sdk/B70_Application_Development_Environment/b70_sdk/b70_sdk/toolchain_win32")
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT ${toolchain_dir}/sysroot)

# set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS 1)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${toolchain_dir}/tools/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc.exe)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-Werror=uninitialized -fvisibility=hidden -fPIC -fpic -fno-short-enums -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -Os")

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS 1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${toolchain_dir}/tools/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++.exe --sysroot=${CMAKE_SYSROOT})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")

# set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM "c:/ninja/ninja.exe")
set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM "${toolchain_dir}/tools/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-make.exe")

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

Comment: Может на `-G Ninja` перейти?

Comment: Попробовал использовать Ninja. Скачал, поставил, установил генератор. Но все одно cmake выдает одну и ту-же ошибку: ```CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: && ```

Comment: Это очень странно, что-то вы нашаманили.

Comment: Вполне возможно. Но я не понимаю в чем дело. тулчейн cmake я свой пишу. Там просто ctrl+c обычного тулчейна со своими путями до кросс компилятора.

Comment: А покажите тулчейн-файл.

Comment: Добавил тулчейн

Comment: Запускаю так:  ```cmake --debug-trycompile .. -G"Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=c:/b70_sdk/B70_Application_Development_Environment/b70_sdk/b70_sdk/toolchain.cmake```